# XNA performance

Tags: c#, xna

I'm writing some sort of Geometry Wars inspired game except with added 2d rigid body physics Ai pathfinding some waypoint analysis line of sight checks load balancing etc. It seems that even though with around 80-100 enemies on screen it can work reasonably fast with all  that stuff enabled the performance completely breaks down once you get to a total of 250 (150 enemies) objects or so. I've searched for any O(n^2) parts in the code but there don't seem to be any left. I'm also using spatial grids.

Even if I disable pretty much everything from the supposedly expensive Ai related processing it doesn't seem to matter, it like still breaks down at 150 enemies.

Now I implemened all the code from scratch, currently even the matrix multiplication code, and I'm almost completely relying on the GC as well as using C# closures for some things, so I expect this to be seriously far from being optimized, but still it doesn't make sense to me that with like 1/15 of the processing work but double the objects the game suddenly starts to slow down to crawl? Is this normal, how is the XNA platform normally supposed to scale as far as the amount of objects being processed is concerned?

I remember Some slerp spinning cube thing I did at first could handle more than 1000 at once so I think I'm doing something wrong?

edit:
Here's the grid structure's class

public abstract class GridBase{

```
    public const int WORLDHEIGHT = (int)AIGridInfo.height;
    public const int WORLDWIDTH = (int)AIGridInfo.width;
    protected float cellwidth;
    protected float cellheight;


    int no_of_col_types;

    // a dictionary of lists that gets cleared every frame
    // 3 (=no_of_col_types) groups of objects (enemy side, players side, neutral)
    // 4000 initial Dictionary hash positions for each group
    // I have also tried using an array of lists of 100*100 cells
    //with pretty much identical results
    protected Dictionary<CoordsInt, List<Collidable>>[] grid;


    public GridBase(float cellwidth, float cellheight, int no_of_col_types)
    {
        this.no_of_col_types = no_of_col_types;
        this.cellheight=cellheight;
        this.cellwidth=cellwidth;

        grid = new Dictionary<CoordsInt, List<Collidable>>[no_of_col_types];
        for (int u = 0; u < no_of_col_types; u++)
           grid[u] = new Dictionary<CoordsInt, List<Collidable>>(4000);

    }

    public abstract void InsertCollidable(Collidable c);
    public abstract void InsertCollidable(Grid_AI_Placeable aic);

    //gets called in the update loop
    public void Clear()
    {
        for (int u = 0; u < no_of_col_types; u++)
            grid[u].Clear();
    }

    //gets the grid cell of the left down corner
    protected void BaseCell(Vector3 v, out int gx, out int gy)
    {
        gx = (int)((v.X + (WORLDWIDTH / 2)) / cellwidth);
        gy = (int)((v.Y + (WORLDHEIGHT / 2)) / cellheight);

    }

    //gets all cells covered by the AABB
    protected void Extent(Vector3 pos, float aabb_width, float aabb_height, out int totalx, out int totaly)
    {
        var xpos = pos.X + (WORLDWIDTH / 2);
        var ypos = pos.Y + (WORLDHEIGHT / 2);
        totalx = -(int)((xpos / cellwidth)) + (int)((xpos + aabb_width) / cellwidth) + 1;
        totaly = -(int)((ypos / cellheight)) + (int)((ypos + aabb_height) / cellheight) + 1;

    }


}
```

public class GridBaseImpl1 : GridBase{

```
    public GridBaseImpl1(float widthx, float widthy)
        : base(widthx, widthy, 3)
    {

    }


    //adds a collidable to the grid /
    //caches for intersection test
    //checks if it should be tested to prevent penetration /
    //tests penetration
    //updates close, intersecting, touching lists
    //Collidable is an interface for all objects that can be tested geometrically
    //the dictionary is indexed by some simple struct that wraps the row and column number in the grid
    public override void InsertCollidable(Collidable c)
    {

        //some tag so that objects don't get checked more than once
        Grid_Query_Counter.current++;

        //the AABB is allocated in the heap
        var aabb = c.CollisionAABB;
        if (aabb == null) return;
        int gx, gy, totalxcells, totalycells;
        BaseCell(aabb.Position, out gx, out gy);

        Extent(aabb.Position, aabb.widthx, aabb.widthy, out totalxcells, out totalycells);

        //gets which groups to test this object with in an IEnumerable (from a statically created array)
        var groupstestedagainst = CollidableCalls.GetListPrevent(c.CollisionType).Select(u =>   CollidableCalls.group[u]);
        var groups_tested_against = groupstestedagainst.Distinct();
        var own_group = CollidableCalls.group[c.CollisionType];


        foreach (var list in groups_tested_against)
            for (int i = -1; i < totalxcells + 1; i++)
                for (int j = -1; j < totalycells + 1; j++)
                {

                    var index = new CoordsInt((short)(gx + i), (short)(gy + j));

                    if (grid[list].ContainsKey(index))

                        foreach (var other in grid[list][index])
                        {

                            if (Grid_Query_Counter.Check(other.Tag))
                            {

                                //marks the pair as close, I've tried only keeping the 20 closest but it's still slow
                                other.Close.Add(c);
                                c.Close.Add(other);

                                //caches the pair it so that checking if the pair intersects doesn't go through the grid        //structure loop again
                                c.CachedIntersections.Add(other);

                                var collision_function_table_id = c.CollisionType * CollidableCalls.size +      other.CollisionType;


                                //gets the function to use on the pair for testing penetration
                                //the function is in a delegate array statically created to simulate multiple dispatch
                                //the function decides what coarse test to use until descending to some complete        //geometric query
                                var prevent_delegate = CollidableCalls.preventfunctions[collision_function_table_id];

                                if (prevent_delegate == null) { Grid_Query_Counter.Put(other.Tag); continue; }

                                var a = CollidableCalls.preventfunctions[collision_function_table_id](c, other);

                                //if the query returns true mark as touching
                                if (a) { c.Contacted.Add(other); other.Contacted.Add(c); }






                                //marks it as tested in this query
                                Grid_Query_Counter.Put(other.Tag);
                            }




                        }


                }

        //adds it to the grid if the key doesn't exist it creates the list first
        for (int i = -1; i < totalxcells + 1; i++)
            for (int j = -1; j < totalycells + 1; j++)
            {
                var index = new CoordsInt((short)(gx + i), (short)(gy + j));

                if (!grid[own_group].ContainsKey(index)) grid[own_group][index] = new List<Collidable>();

                grid[own_group][index].Add(c);
            }
    }


    [...]
}
```

Comment: Since you do not show any code to repro your issue I am right now looking into my glass sphere. Please provide some code which exhibits this behaviour or use a profiler to check into which limitation you did run into.

Comment: Well I'm not having a problem with a particurlar piece of code, my question has to do with what the "normal" amount of objects that XNA can handle (when running a physical simulation) is supposed to be.

By looking over the profiler's results it seems that it spends a lot of time using a 10 000 cell grid implemented with a Dictionary but it doen't seem to matter even if I change the implementation to arrays or not use the grid at all.

Comment: I agree with @AloisKraus. XNA can render very detailed and complicated scenes as long as you're doing it right. And to see if that's the case, we'll need to see some code/pseudocode.

For example - is your application CPU-bound? GPU-Bound? How many draw calls do you make per frame? How many state changes? What about textures? Do you use Geometry shaders? What is the GPU/CPU you're running this on? And so on and so forth.

Comment: It really depends in that case

Comment: So far the graphics rendering is just placeholder, t's only using polyLine strips to render simple rectangles and circles (1 draw call per object) I'll try to update the post with the grid structure which seems to be slowing things down

Comment: Ok, let's start with the platform, 360, Windows or Windows Phone 7?

Comment: " t's only using polyLine" have you set the FillMode to wireframe? This always drags my games down to a crawl, it seems to take far more time to render the wireframes than a filled shape.

Comment: Yeah it's drawing the wireframe, it doesn't seem to be a rendering issue though, I just disabled entering the enemies on the grid and the code could draw around 8000 enemies at 60fps (with motion equations but no collisions). It has something to do with  the code that handles collisions it's either using too much memory for the grid or just can't handle resolving the collisions of more than 100 GW style enemies (possibly packed or overlapping) So I guess before I try to optimize it, I need to know what kind of performance should I roughly expect doing this?

Comment: Take it out of XNA, test your collision logic in a separate C# Console App or something with randomized data and see how it performs.

Answer (score 2):

First. Profile your code. Even if you just use manually inserted time stamps to surround blocks you're interested in. I prefer to use the profiler that comes built into Visual Studio Pro.

However, based in your description, I would assume your problems are due to too many draw calls. Once you exceed 200-400 draw calls per frame your performance can drop dramatically. Try batching your rendering and see if this improves performance.

Comment: Whilst a fine answer about profiling in the first part, OP has stated that it is not a rendering issue for the last paragraph.  _"it doesn't seem to be a rendering issue though, I just disabled entering the enemies on the grid and the code could draw around 8000 enemies at 60fps"_

Answer (score 0):

You can use a profiler such as [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to see what may be the problem.

Without any code theres not much I can do.